# How Can I Totally Reset Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redis, resque

My Rails app runs on Heroku using Resque backed by RedisCloud.

Somehow Resque has gotten totally hosed. A few days ago it stopped showing what was currently working (Overview and Working tabs on resque web). I tried to solve it by "cleaning up" what appeared to me to be stale keys in Redis.

Bad move! Now, failed jobs stopped showing up on the Failed tab (and no failed key in Redis).

At this point I would like to do a clean reset, but how? I basically wiped all keys, following the process of this gem: [resque-reset](https://github.com/wegowise/resque-reset/blob/master/lib/resque/tasks/reset.rake).  What else can be done? Where is state kept besides Redis?  Of course I also did `heroku restart`.

But it's still hosed. That is, resque web never shows what's working or what's failed.

Comment: Afaik if you can you flush your db that would be good to reset resque `i.e redis.flushdb`

Comment: I have deleted all entries for Resque (i.e., ```Resque.redis.keys == []```). I use Redis for caching, and prefer not to trash everything unless truly necessary.